# Q: How could I detect if target application hide to background in instruments?

Tags: ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to test monkey test on iOS Xcode instruments, and there exist a problem:
If the target app be hided to background, the script would be stopped after manually launch the app.
How could I detect the app be hided to background? Then I could kill the process and run script again or launch the app.

I used command line as following:

```
instruments -D "${UIA_resultPATH}/monkey/$DATE" -t "${UIA_automationPATH}/Template/Template.UIAutoMonkey.tracetemplate" -w "${UIA_device}" "${UIA_appPATH}" -e UIASCRIPT "${UIA_automationPATH}/UIAutoMonkey/test_suite.js"
```

Comment: Modified:If the target app be hided to background, the script would be stopped "before" manually launch the app.